# How to fix "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in..." error in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

on one of my Wordpress-pages there is the following error displayed:

> "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /kunden/468984_82031/vdhrr.com/wp-content/plugins/acfml/classes/class-wpml-acf.php
>   on line 40"

I think it has something to do with the builder Elementor oder the Plugin "Wordfence". Problem is, I cannot login to my WP-Account. If I try to enter the page I get the some error as about including this:

> "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /kunden/468984_82031/vdhrr.com/wp-content/plugins/acfml/classes/class-wpml-acf.php:40)
>   in /kunden/468984_82031/vdhrr.com/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line
>   1219"

If I look into the line 40 at the "class-wpml-acf.php"-file I get this:

```
foreach ( $active_plugins as $plugin ) {
    if ( stristr( $plugin, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'acf.php' ) ) {
        $active = true;
        break;
     }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix the error, so I can login to Wordpress again and make the message disapear?

Cheers
RH

Comment: Where does `$active_plugins` come from? It's clearly not an array (or other iterable type). My best guess is that it is `null`. You could test that by putting `if(is_iterable ($active_plugins)) { ... }` around your foreach. That way it will only run when `$active_plugins` is iterable.

Comment: thank you so much! It worked... 
Not sure where the `$active_plugins` comes from.